# ffmpeg concat vidoes Could not find codec parameters for stream 1

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to concat 3 vidoes, each is converted to mpg beforehand, when I run the command to concat, it gives me this error (But still produces the output with no audio)

```
Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize'  options
Input #0, mpeg, from 'concat:intermediate1.mpg|intermediate2.mpg|intermediate3.mpg':
Duration: 00:00:25.73, start: 0.540000, bitrate: 2626 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 480x414 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:69], 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels
[mpeg @ 0000000002766ba0] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 130KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
Output #0, mpeg, to 'intermediate_all.mpg':
Metadata:
encoder  : Lavf57.50.100
Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 480x414 [SAR 1:1 DAR 80:69], q=2-31, 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg @ 0000000002766ba0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0.  This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the   timestamps properly
frame= 1151 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    7834kB time=00:00:40.81  bitrate=1572.5kbits/s speed= 346x
video:7792kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.535638%
```

First and third videos are made by just one picture (first one 10 second and the third 5 second long) and there is no audio for them.
the Second video which has Audio, is converted to mpg from mov by running this command :

```
-i test.mov -qscale:v 1 -y intermediate2.mpg
```

And I'm using this command to merge them all together:

```
-i concat:\"intermediate1.mpg|intermediate2.mpg|intermediate3.mpg\" -c copy -y intermediate_all.mpg
```

the final output "intermediate_all.mpg" has no audio at all.

I also tried putting 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' to value 100M, yet didn't work.

Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your first file has no audio so the 2nd file's audio stream header is most certainly beyond the default probe size. But why convert to MPG? Use the concat demuxer after adding a dummy audio track to the files without them.

Comment: @Mulvya I need to convert them to mpg because not all of my "first Videos" have the same size and format, I looked it up somewhere saying to first convert them to mpg. I have also changed the probesize to 100M, isn't it enough?
Can you give me an example?

Comment: Probesize requirement depends on the duration of the first video. In any case, you'll still need a dummy audio for the other files. Don't convert to MPG, use MP4 instead. Add `-f lavfi -i anullsrc -ac 2` after `-i video` when converting if the source has no audio.

Comment: @Mulvya So I did that. Now when I want to concat with '-i concat:\"intermediate1.mp4|intermediate2.mp4|intermediate3.mp4\" -c copy -y intermediate_all.mp4', it  doesn't work. It stops with no proper output...

Comment: You have to use the concat [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) with MP4s.

Comment: Actually I just tried your approach with mpg, and it works!  I wil try demuxer as well.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my first and third video do not contain any audio stream, I need to add some dummy audio first. So with the help of @Mulvya, here is the answer:

My first video (no audio):

```
-i Begining.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -ac 2 -qscale:v 1 -shortest -y intermediate1.mpg
```

My third video (no audio):

```
-i Ending.mp4 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -ac 2 -qscale:v 1 -shortest -y intermediate3.mpg
```

My second video (With audio):

```
-i test.mov  -qscale:v 1 -y intermediate2.mpg
```

And then concat them all together:

```
-i concat:\"intermediate1.mpg|intermediate2.mpg|intermediate3.mpg\" -c copy -y intermediate_all.mpg
```

Finally, convert intermediate_all.mpg to final.mp4:

```
 -i intermediate_all.mpg -qscale:v 1 -y final.mp4
```

Although it was suggested not to convert to mpg, I tried the approach and the final mp4 was a bit distorted. I Used concat demuxer:

```
 -f concat -i videos.txt -c copy -y final.mp4
```

So if there is a way to work around the distorted video, going directly with mp4 would be the fastest way.